# Create a table in cassandra with compound key and n values

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am attempting to create a Cassandra table with a compound key **(IMEI, COMMAND)** and a dynamic list of values. I created an app that ingests any file from any source, as well as a manifest declaring the schema, and then it will write to any number of databases. My Cassandra implementation of **IWriter** needs a schema, but I am stuck on this.

Comment: can you give more detail on this. what is your problem?
do you have separate table like one table in which IMEI is primary key and another table in which COMMAND is primary key, then in 3rd table you can create compound key.

Comment: 'code'/* 
CREATE TABLE imei (Processlogid1 varchar, SessionHistoryId1 varchar, CompanyId1 varchar, SerialNumber1 varchar, SessionHistoryType1 varchar,
CompanyId2 varchar, SerialNumber2 varchar, SessionHistoryType2 varchar, SessionHistoryTypeId varchar, DeviceInternalId varchar,
UserInternalId varchar, PackageId varchar, ServiceId varchar, StationId varchar, UniqueDeviceId varchar PRIMARY KEY, UniqueDeviceId2 varchar, UniqueDeviceId3 varchar,
ErrorCode2 varchar, Message2 varchar);

Comment: This is just an example... I want to have the PK defined, but the values dynamically populated. Make sense?